# Performance of integer casts and rounding

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, firefox, opera

**Note: I asked this a while ago and it didn't get any answers but it did make me create an interesting fiddle, which is at the end of the post. Check the comments if you're interested. In short, `trunc` and `imul`, new additions to the standard, are there to fill a gap when it comes to treating certain types of values properly, without just turning them into `0`. Try the fiddle and look at the chart, it should all be clear. Also, check the perf for an idea of the performance difference.**

### original post

**tl;dr: Is there ever a reason to use the new `Math.trunc`, especially when going for performance? Would the same apply to `Math.ceil`?** *(ps: sorry if I don't make much sense, been up all night, can hardly think clearly :'( )*

Earlier today I was reading up on what new ES6 stuff I can use in Firefox and Chrome. That was when I came across `Math.imul` (integer multiplication, 32-bit) and `Math.trunc` (truncates number to integer part). `Math.trunc` struck me as odd that it would exist, since that same truncation can simply be done with `Math.imul(n, 1)` where `n` is a floating point number. I had forgotten that the same thing can be done with bitwise operations, but after a bit of searching I found 2 SO questions that where related:

- [`Math.trunc` vs `|0` vs `<<0` vs `>>0` vs `&-1` vs `^0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156688/math-trunc-vs-0-vs-0-vs-0-vs-1-vs-0)
- [How does ~~ work as math.floor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277172/how-does-work-as-math-floor?lq=1)

However, neither there nor anywhere else did I find information on comparative performance. So I made a quick jsperf and it benched `Math.imul(Math.PI, 1)` at 50 times faster than `Math.trunc(Math.PI)`. So I thought something's up, since, if `Math.imul` is so much faster, why would anyone ever use `Math.trunc` and why add it into the spec when `Math.imul` can do its job?

After reading the aforementioned questions, I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6UEUk/41/embedded/result/) which builds a table with all the return values for various inputs to relevant functions (including the bitwise operations). As mentioned in the threads, they behave differently depending on their input - bitwise operations deal only with numbers (and treat *everything* as a number obviously), while the `Math` functions, excluding `imul` care about whether their input is a number or not. So, now there's *some* reason why we would need `trunc`.

I made another jsperf and it confirmed what the table showed, that `imul` behaves *exactly* like a bitwise operation. Which raises a new question: why do we have `Math.imul`, also part of  the new spec, when we already have the widely used bitwise operators? The jsperf also showed another interesting fact: `Math.floor` *doesn't* treat its input like the bitwise functions *but* it's just as fast! 0_o

So I've gone from, "why have `trunc`" to "why have `imul`" to "why not do everything through `floor`?". In fact, if you look at the fiddle I made and uncomment certain test functions, you *can* emulate both `ceil` and `trunc` through `floor` (if you don't care about `-0`). I ran a silly jsperf that showed that emulating `ceil` through `floor` was just as fast, and emulating `trunc` through `floor` actually was ~10 times faster than `trunc` itself. Then I fixed it to check for all types of input and it now seems (on Firefox) that I get exactly what should be expected: emulating `trunc` and `ceil` through `floor` gives the same performance as calling them directly. *However* that's only if you care about getting `NaN` when `NaN` is the input and stuff like that. If you *don't* care about those and *especially* if you know all your numbers are floating point, you can get many times the performance of `ceil` out of `floor` by simply doing `Math.floor(n+1)`.

Finally here's the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/round-with-math-imul-vs-math-trunc/8). Firefox absolutely *destroys* Chrome on these kinds of operations (dat asm.js optimization), but the results are unclear to me. So:

- First of all, are my tests (both the fiddle and perf) even correct?
- Is the need to check for non-integer input *that* important when you're casting *to* an integer? (because if not, the naive `ceil` emulation will grant loads more performance)
- Have I missed any other behaviors that these functions have, that would justify having `trunc` for instance?

It seems to me, the bitwise operators are shorter, faster and more efficient when it comes to casting to integers or even rounding (if done carefully). Is there any good reason to use something like `Math.trunc` other than code clarity?

edit - [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6UEUk/43/embedded/result/) with polyfill from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) -- also, someone updated the jsperf with the polyfill [here](http://jsperf.com/round-with-math-imul-vs-math-trunc/9)

Comment: Is `Math.imul` 50 times faster on *all* browsers, or just whichever you tested on? And is it faster in synthetic tests or in everyday situations? Is it properly supported by all browsers? Especially all browsers *in use* (which means even a few year old versions)?

Comment: I could be wrong but, You compare `Math.trunc` to `Math.ceil` for performance, shouldn't you use the polyfill from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, `Math.imul` was 50x when specifically comparing it to `Math.trunc` with `Math.PI` as input on Firefox. I only tested Chrome after I fixed my jsperf. The whole ~50 times thing is an artifact of my bad perf crafting. Opera seems to perform and behave like Chrome in pretty much everything so I only ran the fiddle on it. These are ES6 features I'm testing, but the bitwise operators, `ceil` and `floor` should be widely supported.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer I'm only measuring Firefox and the Blink browsers. I'm testing the whole thing because I'm writing an extension for both, so I'm ignoring IE and Safari, though I would be interested in how they perform on the bitwise operations and how they implement the older `Math` functions.

Comment: Sorry but, I don't feel like that is an answer to my question, I could possibly be misunderstanding your post a bit, but I fail to see how your comment reply is even related to my question.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer sorry, you're right. I just can't think clearly now. I didn't add the polyfill originally since MDN says Chrome supports `trunc` but it clearly does not. I'll add it and post the new version of the fiddle and perf.

Comment: Math.imul is needed for multiplying 32 bit integers. It's not primarily intended for casting.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's obvious, but what's your argument? That despite the performance hit of the _intended way_ we shouldn't examine alternatives? If you know your data, know what you need from it, validate it and understand the different casting methods, it can be an order of magnitude faster to use `imul` or the bitwise casts.

Comment: That's fine, and I was surprised to see it operating so much faster. I was just addressing this: "Which raises a new question: why do we have Math.imul, also part of the new spec, when we already have the widely used bitwise operators?" Math.imul is there to fill a gap.

Comment: @curiousdannii I know. If you see the original question and the fiddle, it all started with "why use `.trunc`" and turned into a whole other thing by the end. I think it's safe to say that both `trunc` and `imul` have a place based on the tables but it's nice to know when not to waste your cpu if you don't need the careful value handling of `trunc` or `imul`. It could avoid a few nasty bugs too :P

Comment: edited the question for those who might come across it.